# Screen Responsive PHP tables in HTML

Tags: php, html, css

So I have an html page that uses PHP calls to fill the various tables. The page looks great on my one screen and horrible everywhere else. Hoping its sort of a simple fix but any feedback would be greatly appreciated. I know I shouldn't use px but the percentage wasn't working correctly for me.

The CSS

```
td.COMPLETE {
background-color: green;
color: black;
text-align: center;
}

td{ 
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
td.Blue {
background-color: blue;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
td.Yellow {
background-color: yellow;
color: black;
text-align: center;
}
td.Orange {
background-color: orange;
color: black;
text-align: center;
}
td.Red {
background-color: red;
color: black;
text-align: center;
}
#dTitle { position: fixed; visibility: visible; left: 1295px; top: 135px;}
#dTable { position: fixed; visibility: visible; left: 1050px; top: 175px;}
#cTitle { position: fixed; visibility: visible; left: 865px; top: 135px;}
#cTable { position: fixed; visibility: visible; left: 855px; top: 175px; width:20%}
#rTitle { position: fixed; visibility: visible; left: 350px; top: 135px;}
#rTable { position: fixed; visibility: visible; left: 50px; top: 175px; width:45%}
#sTitle { position: fixed; visibility: visible; left: 450px; top: 550px; }
#sTable { position: fixed; visibility: visible; left: 50px; top: 590px; width:60%}
```

The HTML

```
<title>Reports</title>
<link href="status.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body bgcolor = #000000>
<font color = "white">
<head>
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="86400">
<center><h1 id="logo"><img src="reports.png" alt="reports logo" height="75" width="75" /><u>Reports</u> </h1></center>
<style> 
        body { 
            animation: fadeInAnimation ease 3s; 
            animation-iteration-count: 1; 
            animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
        } 
        @keyframes fadeInAnimation { 
            0% { 
                opacity: 0; 
            } 
            100% { 
                opacity: 1; 
            } 
        } 
    </style> 
</head>


<?php

  try

  {

    $db = new PDO("sqlite:root/.db");
    $count = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) from reported');
    foreach($count as $row)
    {
            print "<center>Total Database Entires: ".$row['COUNT(*)']. "</center>";
    }
    print "<div id=dupiTitle><h4>Progress</h4></div>";
    print "<div id=dupiTable><table border=10 bordercolorlight=#383838 bordercolordark=Gray>";
    print "<tr><td><u>Operator</u></td><td><u>Total Reports</u></td><td><u>Unique Users</u></td><td><u>Percent of reports Entered</u></td></tr>";
    $result = $db->query('SELECT operator, COUNT(DISTINCT userID), COUNT(userID) FROM reported GROUP BY operator ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT userID) DESC');

    foreach($result as $row)
    {

      print "<tr><td>".$row['operator']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['COUNT(userID)']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['COUNT(DISTINCT userID)']."</td>";

    $sql = "SELECT dupi, COUNT(DISTINCT userID) FROM reported WHERE operator = '" .$row['operator'] ."' AND report is NULL";

    $results = $db->query($sql);
    $complete = "COMPLETE";
    foreach($results as $rows)
    {
    if ($rows['COUNT(DISTINCT userID)'] == 0){
    print "<td class=".$complete.">COMPLETE</td></tr>";
    }elseif(100 - round(($rows['COUNT(DISTINCT userID)']/$row['COUNT(DISTINCT userID)']) * 100) == 100){
    print "<td>99%</td></tr>";
    }else{
    $per = 100 - round(($rows['COUNT(DISTINCT userID)']/$row['COUNT(DISTINCT userID)']) * 100);
    print "<td>" .$per. "%</td></tr>";
    }
    }
    }
    print "</table></div>";
        echo "<div id=cTitle><h4>Color Break Down</h4></div>";
    print "<div id=cTable><table border=10 bordercolorlight=#383838 bordercolordark=Gray>";
    print "<tr><td><u>Color Code</u></td><td><u>Count</u></td></tr>";
        $result = $db->query("SELECT color_code,COUNT(*) FROM reported GROUP BY color_code ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC");
    foreach($result as $row)
            {
            print "<tr><td class=".$row['color_code'].">".$row['color_code']."</td>";
            print "<td>".$row['COUNT(*)']."</td></tr>";
        }
        print "</table></div>";

    echo "<div id=rTitle><h4>Top Reported</h4></div>";
    print "<div id=r><table border=10 bordercolorlight=#383838 bordercolordark=Gray>";
    print "<tr><td><u>Operator</u></td><td><u>Username/UserID</u></td><td><u>Report</u></td><td><u>Times Reported</u></td></tr>";
    $result2 = $db->query('SELECT operator, userID, report, COUNT(*) FROM reported  WHERE report is NOT NULL AND report is NOT "TEST" AND report is NOT "Not Found" AND report is NOT "Restricted" AND report is NOT "Not Verified" GROUP BY report ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 10');

    foreach($result2 as $row)
    {

      print "<tr><td>".$row['operator']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['userID']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['report']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['COUNT(*)']."</td></tr>";

    }
    print "</table></div>";

    echo "<div id=rTitle><h4>Top Reasons Reported</h4></div>";
    print "<div id=rTable><table border=10 bordercolorlight=#383838 bordercolordark=Gray>";
    print "<tr><td><u>Reason</u></td><td><u>Times Reported</u></td></tr>";
    $result2 = $db->query('SELECT explanation, COUNT(*) FROM reported GROUP BY explanation ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 10');

    foreach($result2 as $row)
    {

      print "<tr><td>".$row['explanation']."</td>";
      print "<td>".$row['COUNT(*)']."</td></tr>";

    }
    print "</table></div>";



    $db = NULL;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: What are "PHP tables"? Do you mean HTML tables you output/populate using PHP?

Comment: Correct my apologies

Comment: Use datatable libraries for fast and quick php table operations

Comment: @MuhammadShahjad what would that look like?

Comment: Check one sample https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/fieldDefaults.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those curious I ended up using the W3.CSS and its container objects. All works as I intended other than a single table which is more than likely something I messed up.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

i don't get what the *meta* tag you set on your html, but try this to make the screen responsive

```
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,0">
```

afterward you can set the screen responsive condition using css

Comment: That meta just causes the page to refresh every hour but I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) by which you can have separate styles for different screen sizes or any HTML5 Boilerplate like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/), by which you don't need to explicitly write media queries. In the case of bootstrap add the library CSS link in your HTML head tag and you are good to go.

- [Example for Responsive Table using media query](https://codepen.io/myasseen/pen/JdPNzv).
- [Example for Responsive table using Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp).

**Suggestion**

- `<center>` tag you are using is depreciated please try to use CSS instead ([Refer me](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)).
- First, add `<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,0">` to your head section.
- The following code snippet you have added in head is causing your page refresh.`<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="86400">` [(Refer me)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).
- Always try to use CSS classes instead of giving styles directly to html elements.
- You can also omit some columns in mobile view (if not mandatory) or else you can enable horizontal scroll for your HTML table [(Refer me)](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_table_responsive).